# How do i use the EXCEPT function to show dropped data over time?

Tags: mdx, except

I want to filter account balances that are over a certain amount, say 1,000 and only show the accounts that WERE over 1,000 at a selected time, and have been dropped when compared to a second selected time.  So if 'Amy' had over 1,000 in the selected month of 'June', and now her balance is below 1,000, i want to see her listed, with new balance.

```
    select [Measures].[Amount] on 0,
      FILTER( [Instrument].[Account Num].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Committed Amt]>1000) 
    ON 1  
    from [TEST]
   where
except({[Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[06]&[2012]}, 
   {[Time].[Calendar Year].  [Month].&[07]&[2012]});
```

Using the above code, i can filter balances over a certain amount.  I am not able to show just the acccounts that have dropped, which is what i am attempting to do by using the EXCEPT function.  Any ideas?  This is MDX code using 2008 Analysis server

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put July in the Where clause and use this condition in the filter:

```
([Measures].[Committed Amt], [Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[06]&[2012]) > 1000 AND [Measures].[Committed Amt] < 1000
```

The query becomes:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Amount] ON 0,
FILTER( [Instrument].[Account Num].MEMBERS, ([Measures].[Committed Amt], [Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[06]&[2012]) > 1000 AND ([Measures].[Committed Amt] < 1000, [Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[07]&[2012])) ON 1  
FROM [TEST]
WHERE ([Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[07]&[2012])
```

In the result you will have the amount in July (if you want to change this then change the where clause) of the instruments that have a Committed Amnt > 1000 in June and < 1000 in July.

Comment: so i should replace what i have in the filter and use your statement instead?

Comment: @John I added the full query.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return [Measures].[Amount] for each [Measures].[Amount] for which [Measures].[Committed Amt] in June was under 1000 and above 1000 in July

```
SELECT
[Measures].[Amount] ON 0
,Filter
( [Instrument].[Account Num].MEMBERS  ,
  ([Measures].[Committed Amt],[Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[06]&[2012]) > 1000
AND
  ([Measures].[Committed Amt],[Time].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[07]&[2012]) > 1000
) ON 1
FROM [TEST]
```